# Connecting a Compaq CQ56 screen to a raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2

I've got this laptop in pieces, a Compaq CQ56.  I want to take the screen and connect it to a raspberry Pi to make a interactive mirror like so many tutorials show.

On the back of the screen it has the serial LP156WH2, which I presume is the exact model of the screen.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to hook this up to my Pi?  Also, will it need power still too?

Comment: The board you have found should work. It's not a fancy one (no USB, no TV tuner, no remote, no speakers) but if you only need an HDMI port it should do it. Don't forget to get a 12V power supply as it's not included. Not going to write an answer here, but you may want to check the link above.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an *LCD Driver Board* that is compatible with your panel. You can find such things on AliExpress and they look like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/7inch-8inch-AT070TN90-92-94-LCD-driver-board-for-car-with-remote-control-key-board-car/1000001923687.html). But this is **only** a pointer. This particular board is **NOT** the one you need. You will have to do your own research. Usually you will have to take apart your laptop and seek the model number of the panel and search for it.

Once you've got it, you simply connect it via HDMI/DVI to your Pi.

Comment: Yeah so as I mentioned in my question I think that is LP156WH2.  Would this work? https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/HDMI-VGA-DVI-Audio-LCD-Driver-Board-For-15-6-LP156WH2-TL-B156XW02-1366x768-LCD/181060846711?hash=item2a28114477:g:TZkAAOSwRqBZm~vz

Comment: That definitively looks promising. I'd buy it. But of course there is no guarantee.